# How to have a responsive grid with a max-width for items on desktop?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

Consider the following example (you may have to paste the code into a separate document to see the effect):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #bfe0f5;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.separation {
  margin: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="separation"></div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The first grid works wonderfully. That is, as the window resizes, the number of columns grows or shrinks based on what can be fit.

However, if there are a very small number of items in the grid (like 1 or 2), I instead want them to adhere to a max width on desktop.

That is, on desktop, if there's only a few items in the grid, I'd want it to look like this:

[image]

On mobile, of course, since the screen space is more limited, then there'd likely only be one per row (and the size as a result would be larger than 300px, to fit up the remaining space).

Basically, the above code works perfectly EXCEPT in the case of when the user is on desktop and there are only 1 or 2 items in the grid. Is it possible to alter the above code to handle that case as well? Because in that case I want the items to adhere to a max width.

I tried just setting the `max-width` property on the items and then disabling it in a media query on mobile screen sizes, but then the problem is that the entire row is still clickable, despite the max-width only being `300px`.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but there is no `grid-element-count` property available. You will need JS to assign the count to a *CSS custom variable* and use that variable to calculate some required `max-width`. (I will check if this even makes sense to myself...)

Comment: Surely there's another way than JS? I mean, I can just set the `max-width` property on the individual items and then set them to `display: contents` to make it so that clicking the row doesn't click the item. That is a solution that works, but I don't really like it because `display: contents` has always had wonky browser support.

Comment: I hear you alright, and I guess you are right as the `auto-fill` answer seems to do the trick. Unless you want another `max-width` than `300px` in desktop, but that can be solved with media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit` when declaring `grid-template-columns`.

> `auto-fill` FILLS the row with as many columns as it can fit. So it creates implicit columns whenever a new column can fit, because it’s trying to FILL the row with as many columns as it can. The newly added columns can and may be empty, but they will still occupy a designated space in the row.

> `auto-fit` FITS the CURRENTLY AVAILABLE columns into the space by expanding them so that they take up any available space. The browser does that after FILLING that extra space with extra columns (as with auto-fill ) and then collapsing the empty ones.

[source](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #bfe0f5;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.separation {
  margin: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="separation"></div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `max-width` on the grid, not the items themselves. In this specific case

```
.grid {
    max-width: 620px;
}
```

should do the trick. (2 * 300px + 20px for the gap).

Comment: Yeah but the number of items in the grid is variable. It could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 30, 57, etc. So would this work in that case too?

Comment: It wouldn't. Sorry, I read your question wrong the first time around.
Try setting the `.grid` to `display: inline-grid` and adding a `max-width: 100%;`. That should give you a grid container that grows and shrinks according to the number of elements in it. `display: grid` is a block level display mode that always uses all of the available width unless the width is explicitly set.